# How do I calculate the minimum geo distance between multiple point combinations faster in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, haversine

I am trying to find the minimum distance between each customer to the store. Currently, there are ~1500 stores and ~670K customers in my data. I have to calculate the geo distance for 670K customers x 1500 stores and find the minimum distance for each customer.

I have created the haversine function below:

```
import numpy as np
def haversine_np(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):

    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(np.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = np.sin(dlat/2.0)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2.0)**2

    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
    miles = 6367 * c/1.609
    return miles
```

and my data set looks like below, 1 data frame for the customer (`cst_geo`) and 1 data frame for the store (`store_geo`). The numbers below are made up as I can't share the snippet of the real data:

| Customer ID | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A123 | 39.342 | -40.800 |
| B456 | 38.978 | -41.759 |
| C789 | 36.237 | -77.348 |

| Store ID | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | 59.342 | -60.800 |
| S2 | 28.978 | -71.759 |
| S3 | 56.237 | -87.348 |

I wrote a for loop below to attempt this calculation but it took >8 hours to run. I have tried to use `deco` but wasn't able to optimize it any further.

```
mindist = []
for i in cst_geo.index:
    dist = []
    for j in store_geo.index:
        dist.append(haversine_np(cst_geo.longitude[i], cst_geo.latitude[i],
                                 store_geo.longitude[j], store_geo.latitude[j]))    
    mindist.append(min(dist))
```

Comment: Use [`scipy.pdist()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html)?

Comment: You could use a k-d tree. The cKDTree from scipy.spatial is a fast implementation of this data structure.

Comment: See if these help out - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57696524/, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34557996/, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44682708/, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34517218/.

Comment: Thank you so much for these links! this link works perfectly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681828/efficient-computation-of-minimum-of-haversine-distances/44682708#44682708

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `geopy`

```
from geopy.distance import geodesic

customers = [
    (39.342, -40.800),
    (38.978, -41.759),
    (36.237, -77.348),
]
stores = [
    (59.342, -60.800),
    (28.978, -71.759),
    (56.237, -87.348),
]
matrix = [[None] * len(customers)] * len(stores)
for index, i in enumerate(customers):
    for j_index, j in enumerate(stores):
        matrix[j_index][index] = geodesic(i, j).meters
```

output

```
[[3861568.3809260903, 3831526.290564832, 2347407.258650098, 2347407.258650098], 
[3861568.3809260903, 3831526.290564832, 2347407.258650098, 2347407.258650098],
 [3861568.3809260903, 3831526.290564832, 2347407.258650098, 2347407.258650098]]
```

you can also have the distance in others units with `kilometers`, `miles`, `feet` ...

Comment: The results are quite incorrect; you applied an invalid distance function.  You projected the global coordinates to a Cartesian plane.  Your results are in incorrectly "stretched" degrees of arc, rather than miles.

Comment: You're right, I've updated my answer

Comment: Much better!  I reversed my vote.

Comment: Hi @AlexisG and Prune, thank you for your inputs, I tried the code above but it takes really long to run still (>1 hr with less than half completed), so instead i tried nested loop with vectorizer. It completed in less than 1 minute.. It's based on this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681828/efficient-computation-of-minimum-of-haversine-distances). Thanks again :)