# How to calculate furthest distance in similar group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, math, gis

Here's my data

```
Point     Group     Longitude       Latitude
A         1               100            101
B         1                99            102
C         1               101            101
D         1               102            101
E         2                90            103
F         2                89            105
G         2                91            104
H         2                92            103
```

What I need is

```
Group     distance    Origin      Destination
1          3.16227         B                D
2          3.60555         F                H
```

Notes: You can use Haversine distance for better approximation, I calculate dataframe above just using pythagorean theorem, below the Haversine equation

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree, DistanceMetric
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    # Radius of earth in kilometers is 6371
    km = 6371* c
    return km
```

Regards

Comment: You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681828/efficient-computation-of-minimum-of-haversine-distances) how to efficiently compute the min haversine distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may can create you own function with `scipy`

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
def yourfunc(y) :
    a = cdist(y[['Longitude', 'Latitude']], y[['Longitude', 'Latitude']], metric='euclidean')
    a_max = a.max()
    idx = np.where(a == a_max)[0]
    return pd.Series([a_max]+y['Point'].iloc[idx].tolist(),index = ['distance','Origin','Destination'])
    
df.groupby('Group').apply(yourfunc)

Out[27]: 
       distance Origin Destination
Group                             
1      3.162278      B           D
2      3.605551      F           H
```

Comment: Is metric is on 'euclidean' geometry? since earth is round I plan to use 'haversine' metric in spherical geometry, but your answer really help, upvoted